# Invalid value at 'start_index' (TYPE_UINT64), "1e+05" [invalid] issue while downloading data to R from BigQuery

Tags: r, google-bigquery, bigrquery

I successfully connected Google BigQuery with the R environment using the `bigrquery` package.

I have defined a `sql` statement which extracts a report. While using the  `bq_table_download` function, I get the following error.

`Invalid value at 'start_index' (TYPE_UINT64), "1e+05" [invalid]`

Code:

`sql <- "SELECT * FROM ABC"`

`df <- bq_project_query(billing, sql)`

`data <-  (bq_table_download(df))`

There is very little help on this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you please let me know, how I can provide a reproducible example in this case? Give you access to the data warehouse ? This is a general error that may be encountered for any GBQ project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is caused as BigQuery allows only 100k records to be downloaded. Adding the
`options(scipen = 20)` script to the start of your code will solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This was just fixed in [PR#400](https://github.com/r-dbi/bigrquery/commit/09c9cf021ec105ef9d5c25aea690c6f57f3a6e02) by [@gjuggler](https://github.com/r-dbi/bigrquery/commits?author=gjuggler)

updating the `bigrquery` package to the latest version will fix your issue.

```
remotes::install_github("r-dbi/bigrquery")
```